# MVC Compress String to send to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, compression

So I have an MVC Application that is needing to send about a 4000 list of items (all about 6-8 characters long) from my view (using javascript) to the controller when navigating. However, it appears that browsers have a maximum length that they allow and you cannot change that.

So what I am needing to do is probably convert it to a string, then compress that string ... a lot, send it to the controller, and then decompress it using c#.

So far I have tried the LZString, but the c# method's that I got from GitHub returns null, so the c# addition to LZString no longer seems to work.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: you want to send 4000 items from your page 1(action 1) to pages 2 (action2)? when use clicks on a link ?

Comment: There is no such hard coded limit for post messages. The url is limited to 2kb but the posted form fields can be megabytes. Thats a server configuration

Comment: try with GZipStream instead

Comment: Well it isn't a post. It's more of a window.location.href = url inwhich url has the 4000 parameter item. The users are wanting the ability to copy a browser link and send it to another user, so all the info has to be in the url.